# Why can't turn off the Sublime 3 updates notification by adding "update_check":false in user setting file?

Tags: windows, editor, sublimetext3, text-editor

I want to turn off the Sublime 3 updates notification, so I go to `Preferences -> Settings-User` and edited it like this:

```js
{
    "auto_close_tags": true,
    "font_size": 18,
    "hot_exit": false,
    "remember_open_files": false,
    "show_encoding": true,
    "update_check": false
}
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Add this line in your host file.

```
127.0.0.1       www.sublimetext.com
```

for linux, host file is `/etc/hosts`
and for windows it is `C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts`

Update : If you want to open sublime website on your browser then make sure to undo these changes.

Comment: I always appreciate alternative smart answers :)

Comment: This is the best way to do it.

Comment: +1 This is the best answer - and the one, which will always work, regardless, what Sublime developers come up with. You may also use: 127.0.0.1   localhost     www.sublimetext.com. But in most cases it is just cosmetic change.

Comment: Thanks. It does have the side effect of killing all access to sublimetext.com in your browser tho, but meh, I guess you will remember it after 15 minutes of pulling hair our when you finally need it!

Comment: any other web address we should block ?

Comment: While it's an interesting workaround, and might suit the OPs need, this doesn't answer the OPs question.

Comment: It does. They want to turn off notifications, and this achieves that.

Answer (score 41):

You need to register the software for `"update_check": false` to work.

https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core/issues/1206#issuecomment-221630273

The deal is that if you're not paying, then your contribution is to help with testing the software, and for that you need to be using the latest version.

Answer (score 12):

There is no way to turn this off, ***unless*** you have [registered](https://sublimetext.com/buy) your version of Sublime. Sublime Text 3 is still in "beta" status, so it is strongly advised that you upgrade when a new version is available to get the latest features and bug fixes. If you don't want to upgrade quite so often, make sure you are using the [public beta](https://sublimetext.com/3) instead of the [dev releases](https://sublimetext.com/3dev), which are updated much more frequently. However, you can't use the dev releases unless you have a license, in which case `"update_check": false` will work as expected.

Comment: This is false.  You can turn the check off, just as the OP is trying to do **iff you have a registered copy of the software**.  I considered a down-vote, but I'm not sure if perhaps you were correct at sometime in the past.

Comment: After much prodding, I've updated the answer to reflect reality, which is that you need to have registered your copy of Sublime, public beta or dev release, in order for the setting to work properly.

Answer (score 11):

Go to *preferences* then *settings-user* then within the `{}` parentheses type:

```
"update_check": false
```

*This only works if you are registered*

Comment: Thank you. I can verify once I entered the license key, it started to work

Answer (score 10):

I did the following after installing sublime text 3:

Modify `/etc/hosts` to include entries:

```
127.0.0.1 www.sublimetext.com
127.0.0.1 sublimetext.com
127.0.0.1 sublimehq.com
127.0.0.1 license.sublimehq.com
127.0.0.1 45.55.255.55
127.0.0.1 45.55.41.223
0.0.0.0 license.sublimehq.com
0.0.0.0 45.55.255.55
0.0.0.0 45.55.41.223
```

And then set `"update_check": false`

Answer (score 1):

Open Sublime Text 3 (ST3), press `CMD + comma` (or click "Sublime Text" > "Preferences" > "Settings") to open your `Preferences.sublime-settings - User` and add `"update_check": false,` to the main JSON object.

This will stop the "upgrade dialog" from appearing every time you launch ST3.

Warning: this ^ may not work on ALL versions of ST3, but it definitely works on ST3 v3.22.2 -- I saw the upgrade to ST4 dialog every single time I launched ST3, and then it stopped once I added this ^^.

Answer (score 0):

open sublime_text binary with hex editor eg, okteta and search for 'characters' [your current version number eg 3126] and replace with the current download version eg 3143 > save > done. (i got the changelog on first run).

note: i found the version no in 2 places. replaced both.

Comment: İts Not Working.