# How to update Sublime text on linux 16.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sublimetext3, ubuntu-16.04

I followed this link to install sublime text:

[Download sublime text ubuntu](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/linux_repositories.html#apt)

And now when open sublime text, it show me

[image]

I've tried run `sudo apt-get update`, but even it show me that alert

What commant might run ?

Comment: This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on the S.E. related sites  http://askubuntu.com OR  http://superuser.com . Use the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. ....

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ,  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask ,  http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: @jjoselon dude go to this link if its help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30208384/why-cant-turn-off-the-sublime-3-updates-notification-by-adding-update-checkf

Answer (score -1):

You can run `sudo apt-get upgrade` to upgrade the sublime text package.

Comment: This answer seemed to have nothing to do with upgrading Sublime Text, at first. Looking the package up with Synaptic indicated there was no possibility of an update.   


I kept looking for an answer and found a an [article in the official documentation](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/linux_repositories.html#apt). 'The apt repository containing packages for both x86-64 and arm64' was added and `sudo apt upgrade` (after `update`, I guess), did just the thing, updating `Sublime Text`.